# How to use UI functions in non UI methods?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want create a own class with utility functions.

Therefore i want to use typical Activity-functions and build something around them.

I want use the setTitle function for example:

```
       public void frameworkSetTitle() {
            String testValue;
            setTitle(testValue);
       }
```

Is it possible to use this functions in own classes and pass the result back to the calling Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the `Activity` instance to the util method and call the desired methods there, like `setTtitle`.

Comment: i specified in another question what i want to build. I'm not sure if passing the Activity would be risky. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45525953/best-way-to-build-an-ui-utility-class

Comment: you can pass activity instance. but dont keep a reference to it that outlives it's lifecycle. In simple terms, dont store the activity instance in any static field. Just do the job inside the method and be done with it.

Comment: The main reason therefor was, to minimize passing variable. If the utility class would provide several methods, like setTitle(), setBackgroundPicture(), setBackgroundAudio() i had the idea with passing only the necessary stuff one time in the constructor, instead of every method it would be comfortable for the utility user.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not recommended, as passing around context can lead to unintended memory leaks.  Flow of information should be uni-directional, anyway.

Your util class should do something more like this:

```
public static String getGeneratedTitle() {
    String titleValue;
    // some work
    return titleValue;
}
```

This way, you can just make a simple call in your activity:

```
myTextView.setText(myUtilClass.getGeneratedTitle());
```

Comment: @freeLearning and also make your activity static so you can access the util methods anywhere without creating an object.

Comment: Edits reflect your input. This should, in most cases, be the best idea.

Comment: I specified in another question what i want to build https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45525953/best-way-to-build-an-ui-utility-class